# Rendering IEnumerable<string> from an entity framework generic repository

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, generics

I am not sure if this is possible.  I have several particular tables in my database represented by entity framework's code first classes.  These classes have different properties except in terms of the Id property which is always a string. I am wondering if there is anyway to create a generic repository that can select and render a sequence of just the Id property.  For example something like:

```
class GetDbIds<T> where T : class
{
    // PROPERTIES
    DbContext DbContext {get;set;}
    DbSet<T> DbSet {get;set;}

    // CONSTRUCTOR
    public GetDbIds(DbContext dbContext)
    {
         DbContext = dbContext;
         DbSet = DbContext.Set<T>();
    }

    // METHODS
    public IEnumerable<string> GenerateNewIdSequence()
    {
         return DbSet.Select(x => x.Id);
    }
}
```

I know how to set up a basic generic repository, but I haven't came across any patterns that also let you dynamically query the repository as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can constrain `T` to an interface that has the property:

```
interface IIdentifiable { string Id { get; } }
class GetDbIds<T> where T : IIdentifiable, class
```

Comment: Pure awesomeness! Thanks for bringing that to my attention.  Perfect solution!